# More bubbles in fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am making a fluid simulation similar to this:
[image]

I want the fluid simulator to create bubbles like in the picture. Blender fluid already creates a few small bubbles, and more depending on the quality of the water, but I want my final product to have many bubbles spread out like in the picture. I don't want to use particles, however, because it is time consuming to do that, and some of the bigger bubbles should stick to the top of the water. Is there some way to add more bubbles to the blender fluid simulator, or some python script to do it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Blender 2.8x vanilla-build (as in the main download on blender.org). But- by all accounts Mantaflow is the way ahead for fluids as well as smoke (I've only used it for smoke myself and it can be rather good!), it's a much more modern simulator (and will be coming in to 'vanilla' Blender soon-ish), but it's a separate Blender installation as it stands, so a bit of a pain. But then again- there's me with Blender 2.79, 2.79 (fracture modifier), 2.81a (vanilla install at the moment), and 2.82 (mantaflow) all installed on most of my machines!...